# How would I remotely send out an update for a Cocoa application for the Mac?

Tags: macos

My game is in alpha, and I'd like to (when I release it) send out updates to people running my program. How would I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Out of interest, what is the game going to be?

Comment: @Coxy Yeah, now I really want to know too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [Sparkle Framework](http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/).

Its features include:

- True self-updating--no work required from the user.
- Uses appcasts for release information.
- Displays release notes to the user via WebKit.
- The user can choose to automatically download and install all updates.
- Displays a detailed progress window to the user.
- Seamless integration—there's no mention of Sparkle; your icons and app name are used.
- Supports authentication for installing in secure locations.
- Supports DSA signatures for ultra-secure updates.
- Really, really easy to install.
- Sparkle requires no code in your app, so it's trivial to upgrade or remove the module.

A lot of well known apps like Pixelmator, Transmission, and Coda use it.

Comment: I did, just had to wait 6 mins before accepting it. Had to go back to my apartment first ;p. But thanks so much!

Comment: @RyanCohen Don't worry about it.